# AsyncFileUpload catch async postback

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, asynchronous, postback, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to catch the asyncpostback after my file was uploaded with the **AsyncFileUpload** control of ASP.NET.

Code is here: http://ideone.com/aU9sQ3

*hint: code is small and is around only about mine problem*

I'm trying to show in label some status, that file has been uploaded.

Firtst of, I thought to catch this with the `Page.IsPostBack` bool state:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack) CheckStatus();
```

Where **CheckStatus()** method edits the label content to show the uploaded status.

But the problem consists on my code is calling this method earlier than file has been uploaded and **AsyncFileUpload.UploadedComplete**

I have tried also to catch with the `Page.IsAsync`, but no success. How can I fix my issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update page UI from UploadedComplete event handler since this control submitting page from hidden frame. Consider to use `OnClientUploadComplete` and `OnClientUploadError` properties to update label in javascript on success upload and on failure.
See sample here: [AsyncFileUpload.aspx](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SampleWebSites/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx)